# saving in a file results in many instances of variables

Tags: android

I am using below function to save some data.
The mydata is double list that user enter and dates_Strings is list (with String as datatype) which contain dates in string format.

```
public void savefunc(){
        
        SimpleDateFormat thedate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.US); 
        Date d=new Date();
        String formattedDate=thedate.format(d);
        dates_Strings.add(formattedDate);
        
        
        double thedata=Double.parseDouble(value.getText().toString().trim());
        mydata.add(thedata);
         
        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File directory = new File (sdCard, "MyFiles");
        directory.mkdirs();            
        File file = new File(directory, filename);

        FileOutputStream fos;

        
        try {
           fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
         
              BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fos));
              for (int i=0;i<mydata.size();i++){
                    bw.write(mydata.get(i)+","+dates_Strings.get(i)+"\n");
              }
              value.setText("");
              bw.flush();
              bw.close();
          
            } catch (IOException e2) {
               e2.printStackTrace();
                }//catch
    }
```

Now , the problem is that when saving the following happens:

For example if I enter  "1" + save , "2" + save ,"3" +save + "4" +save...

In the file I can see

> 1.0 -> 07/05/13
>
> 1.0 -> 07/05/13
>
> 2.0 -> 07/05/13
>
> 3.0 -> 07/05/13
>
> 3.0 -> 07/05/13
>
> 4.0 -> 07/05/13

Comment: and what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: @Thrakbad:I enter "1" only one time ,not 2 or 3.

Comment: Where is `mydata` declared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  fos = new FileOutputStream(file,true);
```

you are instantiating `FileOutputStream` with append flag. If `mydata` is never cleared, its cotent will be write in the file everytime you call `savefunc`

Comment: what kind is mydata ? try with mydata.clear() before mydata.add(thedata);

Answer (score 1):

What you should see in the file is more something like

```
1.0 -> 07/05/13
1.0 -> 07/05/13
2.0 -> 07/05/13
1.0 -> 07/05/13
2.0 -> 07/05/13
3.0 -> 07/05/13
1.0 -> 07/05/13
2.0 -> 07/05/13
3.0 -> 07/05/13
4.0 -> 07/05/13
```

Thats because when you write `myData` to the file you always write the whole list, including the numbers you've written before. So the first save writes `1.0`, the second save writes `1.0` and `2.0` and so on. You can fix this by instantiating your `FileOutputStream` with `fos = new FileOutputStream(file,false);`, then it won't append the new data to the file, but overwrite it. Or you could just write the newly saved number alone to the file with append mode. Depends on your use-case which one is better.

EDIT: What I meant by write the number alone would be something like this:

instead of

```
for (int i=0;i<mydata.size();i++){
    bw.write(mydata.get(i)+","+dates_Strings.get(i)+"\n");
}
```

You write

```
bw.write(thedata + "," + formattedDate + "\n");
```

Comment: :Yes, exactly this is the file!I want to append data because I want to use them.You said "you could just write the newly saved number alone to the file with append mode".I didn't understand that.Can you show an example please?Thanks!

Comment: :Thanks for the answer but i just prefer to use data.clear(). :) .I am upvoting.